# JAVA: [-255...255] int to 2 bytes array

Tags: java, integer, int, byte

I have an integer that can only contains values between - 255 and 255. I know that it can be represented with 2 bytes (I'm right?) 
How can I convert this int to 2 bytes array? Many thanks

Comment: Well what do you want the format of the array to be? There are various ways you *could* represent it.

Comment: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

Comment: Why not use short array? That's 2 bytes! Or you could have a bit list of all the numbers and access them by calculating individual offsets and parsing them appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than store in two distinct bytes and implement your own custom encoding and decoding, it would be easiest to store these values in a `short`. This is a 16 bit signed integer with sufficient range for your values.

Comment: Great, many thanks! And what if I have a [0...255] int and want to store in a SINGLE byte?

Comment: That would be another question but it's easy enough to answer. Use two's complement. From int in range [0..255] -> single byte, if the value is >=128 store value - 256. And in the other direction, if the stored value is negative, add 256 to it.